# use multiple .dtx file to make only .sty file

Tags: package-writing, dtx

I would like to split the voluminous .dtx of eledmac in multiple .dtx file.
1) one for the user handbook
2) many other for the package code + handbook.

So my objectives are:
1) have multiple .dtx file
2) but produce one .sty file and one .pdf file

what is the best way?

Comment: Why do you want to write the user handbook in DTX? Might be easier to manage that in normal LaTeX. That is how `memoir` is handled. The documented source might not be that relevant for the casual user. So having two PDFs might be better (might even leave out the PDF of the documented source code)

Comment: you are right. Hovewer, for now,  the eledmac user handbook and the documentation are in the same file, which I have inherited from previous developer. But as my objectif is to separat as much as possible what is relevant for user and what is for developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite straight-forward to split the code for a single `.sty` over multiple sources: after all, the `.dtx` format was created to support the work of the LaTeX team where there is a significant need for this type of thing. The `\generate` macro takes two arguments where the second can have multiple source files

```
\input docstrip
\generate{mypackage.sty}{%
  \from{mysource1.dtx}{package}%
  \from{mysource2.dtx}{package}%
  \from{mysource3.dtx}{package}%
  ...
}
```

In terms of making a single PDF, that comes down to having a source file that will generate the documentation and then typesetting it.  Depending on exactly how you want to set things up, you might have a simple `.tex` file for the user documentation, might use a `.dtx` or might arrange that the user documentation is inside the code `.dtx` files and only the user part of each one is read by a master `.tex` file. However, that does not depend at all on where your code sources are.

Comment: I was stupid. I didn't thing about duplicate the \from command.